# how to store data in an array in a recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have made a recursive function, and I want to add the data it returns to an array each time the function is called.

This is my current implementation:

```php
public function getParentCategory($categoryId) {   
    $category = Category::find($categoryId);
    if($category != NULL){
        $catArray[]  = $category->id;
        if($category->parent_category_id != NULL) {
            $this->getParentCategory($category->parent_category_id);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to store data in `catArray` each time the function is called.

Comment: Try this using array_merge() `if($category->parent_category_id != NULL){
$catArray = array_merge($catArray, $this->getParentCategory($category->parent_category_id););
            }`

Comment: @PhpDeveloper, that's unlikely to work: `$catArray` is not only out of scope, it's not even defined the first time it's used.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the data from the function. You also need to *pass* it to the function, or use a default parameter:

```
public function getParentCategory($categoryId, $catArray = array()) {   
    $category = Category::find($categoryId);
    if ($category != NULL){
        $catArray[]  = $category->id;
        if ($category->parent_category_id != NULL){
            $catArray = $this->getParentCategory($category->parent_category_id, $catArray);
        }
    }
    return $catArray;
}
```

You can use `array_unshift()` instead of `$catArray[]=` to have `$catArray` in reverse order (and/or add `$category->id` *after* the return from the recursion).